# Lua: efficiently operate (read/write) on C-style, C-allocated dynamic arrays in lua

Tags: c, lua

Assume that I have allocated a C-style dynamic array of doubles in C/C++ code, I thus have:

```
double *x; //Pointing to beginning of allocated memory
int size; //Size of array
```

Is it possible to write lua code (or even C/C++ code to be used in lua) such that a C/C++ embedded instance of lua can read/write efficiently on the elements of this "view" on the array?

I would just need support for the following C++ operations:

```
double y = x[2]; //Reading
x[2] = 3.0; //Writing
int vecSize = x.size(); //Size of array
```

No memory management is needed (nor wanted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, export the pointer as userdata and set __index and __newindex metamethods.

Comment: Could I use lightuserdata instead? It's my understanding that userdata is garbage-collected...

Comment: @KRao: lightuserdata cannot have metamethods. But you can use full userdata containing just the pointer, not the whole memory block. That's a typical situation for C-side memory.

Comment: And we also have the __len metamethod for the length operator #, as well as __gc for garbage collection if one should ever need that.

Comment: To be more precise, you can use a C struct `{ double *x; int size;}`,   allocate it in C and set a full userdata to the pointer and suitable metamethods. (Of course, you also need to allocate the vector x as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try the latest [LuaJIT 2.0](http://luajit.org/luajit.html) by Mike Pall, with it's new FFI interface (still under development).

It enables you to directly manipulate C structures and arrays from Lua, using natural Lua syntax. Example quoted from the LuaJIT documentation:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct { uint8_t red, green, blue, alpha; } rgba_pixel;
]]

local function image_ramp_green(n)
  local img = ffi.new("rgba_pixel[?]", n)
  local f = 255/(n-1)
  for i=0,n-1 do
    img[i].green = i*f
    img[i].alpha = 255
  end
  return img
end
```

If you cannot use LuaJIT, use the standard Lua userdata, which you can allocate any size you need (`size * sizeof(double)`), and create appropriate `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods to access the elements using `array[i]`.

You cannot use lightuserdata this way, because you cannot set their metatable, but you could use it like this: `value = get(array, i); set(array, i, value)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am really new to Lua :) I am absolutely fine with a syntax like value = get(array, i); set(array, i, value). As such I will explore this solution and the one which uses LuaJIT.